# Showing that $k[x]$ is integral over $k[x^2-1]$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, integral-extensions

For context I am working on Atiyah-Macdonald 5.4.

I want to show that the extension $k[x^2-1]\subset k[x]$ is integral. I believe this is the case using that $k[x^2-1]=k[x^2]$, which I believe can be proved using
$$(x^2-1)+1=x^2$$
This equality feels, and looks, obviously true. But if it is, why present the ring as $k[x^2-1]$ and not $k[x^2]$?

I am either missing something obvious, or there is some "pedagogical" reason which isn't clear. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are right, and the authors might have presented the ring like this to let you discover this equality. Alternatively, you can check directly that $x$ is integral over $k[x^2-1].$